# Grouping large datasets into specific criteria

Tags: r

I am trying to organize a large datasets of channels and group them into specific criteria.

For example given a column in a data frame

```
Channel_List       
Nat Geo
Discovery
CNBC
CNN
HBO
Fox HD
Cartoon Network
```

The goal is to organize and label the following channels into their specific groups on a separate column respective to its channels. For example the ideal output would be

```
Channel_List        Genre 
Nat Geo             Documentary
Discovery           Documentary
CNBC                News
CNN                 News
HBO                 Entertainment
Fox HD              Entertainment
Cartoon Network     Entertainment
```

Do I have to use `if()` and equality statements hard coded into R code that equates each channel into their specific genre? What is the best and most efficient way to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: Alternatieve: Manually create a lookup-table witrh all unique Channel_Lists and their genre, then perform a (left) join with your data and the lookup-table.

Comment: do you have a example of the code using lookup.  I tried using table lookup however since the number of genres in this case 3 genres is less than the number of channels. Using the "match data.frame" has error because the number of data of channel_list (7 channels) and number of genres (3 genres) is different.

Comment: read about left joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alternative for `if` is `dplyr`'s `case_when()`

```
df <- data.frame( Channel_List = c("Nat Geo" , "Discovery", "CNBC", "CNN", "HBO", "Fox HD", "Cartoon Network"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
#create vectors with channels per group
documentary.v <- c( "Nat Geo", "Discovery" )
news.v <- c( "CNBC", "CNN" )
entertainment.v <- c( "HBO", "Fox HD", "Cartoon Network" )
#use case_when to determine in which Genre the channel_list belongs
df %>% mutate( Genre = case_when( Channel_List %in% documentary.v ~ "Documentary",
                                  Channel_List %in% news.v ~ "News",
                                  Channel_List %in% entertainment.v ~ "Entertainment",
                                  TRUE ~ NA_character_)
               )

#      Channel_List         Genre
# 1         Nat Geo   Documentary
# 2       Discovery   Documentary
# 3            CNBC          News
# 4             CNN          News
# 5             HBO Entertainment
# 6          Fox HD Entertainment
# 7 Cartoon Network Entertainment
```